# How can I control the rate at which an element's property animates, rather than the duration?

Tags: jquery

Rather than taking a specific time to complete an animation, I'd like the duration to be a function of the difference of the start and end values. In other words, the animating property of something far away should change the same rate as something that is close.

I've managed to get this working by manually altering the duration, but that doesn't really provide a robust enough solution for what I'm looking to accomplish.

HTML:

```
<div class="container" id="wrong">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
</div>

<div class="container" id="right">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container { position: relative; float: left; width: 100px; height: 200px; }
.container > div { width: 50px; height: 50px; position: absolute; }
.top { background-color: red; }
.middle { background-color: blue; left: 50px; top: 50px; }
```

JS:

```
var fin      = { top: '100px' },
    duration = 2000;

var animate = function() {
    $('.top').css('top', 0);
    $('.middle').css('top', '50px');

    $('#wrong > div').animate(fin, duration, 'linear');

    $('#right .top').animate(fin, duration, 'linear');
    /* half the distance so use half the time */
    $('#right .middle').animate(fin, duration/2, 'linear');
};

animate()
setInterval(animate, 3000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SrQ77/

Comment: When waiting for the callback of `animate` to fire, if the distance is 0 you get stuck waiting for a no-op animation to finish - something I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> speed = distance / time

you can arrange it so that

> time = distance / speed

and you also want the animation to run at the same speed. So you can neglect the speed variable and go ahead with just

> time = distance

You can use https://api.jquery.com/offset/ to help you find out the distance

Answer (score 1):

you have to calculate it.

http://jsfiddle.net/SrQ77/1/

```
var fin      = 100,
    duration = 2000;

var animate = function() {

    $('.top').css('top', 0);
    $('.middle').css('top', '50px');
    $('#wrong .top').animate({top: fin+'px'}, ((fin - $('#wrong .top').position().top) / fin) * duration, 'linear');
    $('#wrong .middle').animate({top: fin+'px'}, ((fin - $('#wrong .middle').position().top) / fin) * duration, 'linear');

    $('#right .top').animate({top: fin+'px'}, duration, 'linear');
    /* half the distance! */
    $('#right .middle').animate({top: fin+'px'}, duration/2, 'linear');
};

animate()
setInterval(animate, 3000);
```